# Could not scrape a Japanese website using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I tried to **scrape** a japanese website by trying some simple tutorial online but I could not get the information from the website. Below is my code:

```
import requests
wiki = "https://www.athome.co.jp/chintai/1001303243/?DOWN=2&BKLISTID=002LPC&sref=list_simple&bi=tatemono"
page = requests.get(wiki)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
for i in soup.findAll('data payments'):
    print(i.text)
```

What I wanted to get is from the below part:

```
                <dl class="data payments">
                    <dt>賃料：</dt>
                    <dd><span class="num">7.3万円</span></dd>
                </dl>
```

I wish to print our the data payment which is "賃料" with price "7.3万円".

Expected(In string):

"payment: 賃料 is 7.3万円"

Edited:

```
import requests
wiki = "https://www.athome.co.jp/"
headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
headers.update({
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0',
})
page = requests.get(wiki,headers=headers)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.decode('utf-8', 'replace'))
```

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to this scraping from website, could you fill me in more. I could not understand your question.

Comment: The website you see when you load it in a browser is often very different from the basic web page that's loaded using `requests`. The reason for that is that your browser starts executing any JavaScript code on the page as soon as it needs to, while `requests` only loads the page itself - none of the scripts linked on it. And even if you get it to load the scripts, it cannot execute them - you'd need to use a headless browser or something similar to load the page and have the JavaScript execute, before you extract the html and analyse with beautifulsoup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your latest version of code, you decode the soup and you will not be able to use functions like `find` and `find_all` in BeautifulSoup. But we will talk about it later.

## To begin with

After getting the soup, you can print the soup, and you will see: (only showing the key part)

```
<meta content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" name="ROBOTS"/>
<meta content="0" http-equiv="expires"/>
<meta content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" http-equiv="expires"/>
<meta content="10; url=/distil_r_captcha.html?requestId=2ac19293-8282-4602-8bf5-126d194a4827&amp;httpReferrer=%2Fchintai%2F1001303243%2F%3FDOWN%3D2%26BKLISTID%3D002LPC%26sref%3Dlist_simple%26bi%3Dtatemono" http-equiv="refresh"/>
```

Which means that you do not obtain enough elements and you are detected as a crawler.

Therefore, there is something missing in @KunduK's answer, there has nothing to do with the `find` function yet.

## Main Part

First of all, you need to make your python script less like a crawler.

### Headers

The headers are most usually used to detect the cralwer. 
In original requests, when you get a session from requests, you can check the headers with:

```
>>> s = requests.session()
>>> print(s.headers)
{'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.22.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
```

You can see that the headers here will tell the server that you are a crawler program, which is `python-requests/2.22.0`.

Therefore, you need to modify the `User-Agent` with updating headers.

```
s = requests.session()
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36',
}
s.headers.update(headers)
```

However, when testing the cralwer, it is still detected as a crawerl. Therefore, we need to dig further in headers part. (But it could be other reason like IP blocker, or Cookie reason. I will mention them later.)

In the Chrome, we open the Developer Tools, and open the website. (To pretend it is your first visit of the website, you had better [clear the cookies](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) first.) After clearing the cookies, refresh the page. We could see in the Network card of Developer Tools, it shows a lot of requests from the Chrome.
[image: Developer Tools in Chrome]

By entering the first attribute, which is `https://www.athome.co.jp/`, we could see a detailed table on the right side, in which the Request Headers are the headers generated by Chrome and used to requests the server of target site. 
[image: Detailed Page of Network Card]

To make sure everthing works fine, you could just add everthing in this Chrome headers to your crawler, and it cannot find out you are the real Chrome or crawler anymore. (For most of sites, but I have also find some sites use starnge setting requiring a special header in every requests.)

I have already digged out that after adding `accept-language`, the website's anti-cralwer function will let you pass.

Therefore, all together, you need to update your headers like this.

```
headers = {
    'accept-language': 'zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.7',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36',
}
s.headers.update(headers)
```

### Cookie

For the explaination of cookie, you can refer to the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie).
To obtain the cookie, there is a easy way. 
First, initial a session and update the header, like I mentioned above.
Second, request to get the page https://www.athome.co.jp, once you get the page, you will obtain a cookie issued by the server.

```
s.get(url='https://www.athome.co.jp')
```

The advantage of requests.session is the session will help you to maintain the cookies, so your next request will use this cookie automatically.

You can just check the cookie you obtained by using this:

```
print(s.cookies)
```

And my result is:

```
<RequestsCookieJar[Cookie(version=0, name='athome_lab', value='ffba98ff.592d4d027d28b', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='www.athome.co.jp', domain_specified=False, domain_initial_dot=False, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=1884177606, discard=False, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False)]>
```

You do not need to parse this page, because you just want the cookie rather than the content.

## To get the content

You can just use the session you obtained to request the [wiki page](https://www.athome.co.jp/chintai/1001303243/?DOWN=2&BKLISTID=002LPC&sref=list_simple&bi=tatemono) you mentioned.

```
wiki = "https://www.athome.co.jp/chintai/1001303243/?DOWN=2&BKLISTID=002LPC&sref=list_simple&bi=tatemono"
page = s.get(wiki)
```

And now, everything you want will be posted to you by the server, you can just parse them with BeautifulSoup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
```

After getting the content you want, you can use BeautifulSoup to get the target element.

```
soup.find('dl', attrs={'class': 'data payments'})
```

And what you will get is:

```
<dl class="data payments">
<dt>賃料：</dt>
<dd><span class="num">7.3万円</span></dd>
</dl>
```

And you can just extract the infomation you want from it.

```
target_content = soup.find('dl', attrs={'class': 'data payments'})
dt = target_content.find('dt').get_text()
dd = target_content.find('dd').get_text()
```

To format it as a line.

```
print('payment: {dt} is {dd}'.format(dt=dt[:-1], dd=dd))
```

**Everything has been done.**

## Summary

I will paste the code below.

```
# Import packages you want.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Initiate a session and update the headers.
s = requests.session()
headers = {
    'accept-language': 'zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.7',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36',
}
s.headers.update(headers)

# Get the homepage of the website and get cookies.
s.get(url='https://www.athome.co.jp')
"""
# You might need to use the following part to check if you have successfully obtained the cookies. 
# If not, you might be blocked by the anti-cralwer.
print(s.cookies)
"""
# Get the content from the page.
wiki = "https://www.athome.co.jp/chintai/1001303243/?DOWN=2&BKLISTID=002LPC&sref=list_simple&bi=tatemono"
page = s.get(wiki)

# Parse the webpage for getting the elements.
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
target_content = soup.find('dl', attrs={'class': 'data payments'})
dt = target_content.find('dt').get_text()
dd = target_content.find('dd').get_text()

# Print the result.
print('payment: {dt} is {dd}'.format(dt=dt[:-1], dd=dd))
```

In crawler field, there is a long way to go.

You had better get the ontline of it, and make full use of the *Developer Tools* in the browser.

You might need to find out if the content is loaded by JavaScript, or if the content is in a iframe.

What's more, you migh be detected as a crawler and be blocked by the server. The anti-anti-crawler technique can only be obtained by coding more frequently.

I suggest you to start with an easier website without the anti-crawler function.

Comment: thank you so much for your explanation and its really help in getting me a gist of how it works but when I try to use your code, it seems like I am getting a NoneType at this line. target_content = soup.find('dl', attrs={'class': 'data payments'})

Comment: I also received the same anti-crawler message when I try to print(soup.prettify()) after this line soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

Comment: The BeautifulSoup is not part of the crawler, it is just a package to help to get attributes from the HTML. We need to concentrate on the requests part if we meet the anti-cralwer message. I have tested the code twice today, it worked for the first time and was blocked for the second time. When requests to get the cookies from the server, there is nothing returned by the server. So the `s.cookies` shows `<RequestsCookieJar[]>`, which is an empty CookieJar. I will test further and edit my answer.

Comment: Can you give me an ideal how I can concentrate on the anti-crawler part? It seems like I keep getting that part. I am still a newbie in this so please kindly guide me through

Comment: Sure, please wait an I have to test it on my own. I will modify my answer when solved the problem.

Comment: I have already updated the content and it could bypass the anti-cralwer setting of the server, hope it will help you. But I think I could not tell you everything, you need to read something and try it on your own. There are too many ways to prevent the cralwer from visiting the webpage, different website have different anti-crawler strategy. It is a work requires a lot of experience.

Comment: I see. thank you so much for the help and also guidance. I have marked this as answer and will try to check more online.

Comment: Thank you. I have already added the necessary links in my answer. If you are a newbie to learn crawler, you do not need to know too much about proxy. With the things I have mentioned above, I suppose you could crawl a lot of webpages. For those need to login, use proxy to access or load data from JavaScript, you might need further information.

Comment: Wow, thank you once again for sharing more info. This add new knowledge to me and I will make sure to remember and study it well. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code.use class-name  with tag to find the element.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
wiki = "https://www.athome.co.jp/chintai/1001303243/?DOWN=2&BKLISTID=002LPC&sref=list_simple&bi=tatemono"
headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
headers.update({
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0',
})
page = requests.get(wiki,headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

for i in soup.find_all("dl",class_="data payments"):
   print(i.find('dt').text)
   print(i.find('span').text)
```

**Output:**

```
賃料：
7.3万円
```

---

If you want to manipulate your expected output.Try that.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
wiki = "https://www.athome.co.jp/chintai/1001303243/?DOWN=2&BKLISTID=002LPC&sref=list_simple&bi=tatemono"
headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
headers.update({
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0',
})
page = requests.get(wiki,headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

for i in soup.find_all("dl",class_="data payments"):
   print("Payment: " + i.find('dt').text.split('：')[0] + " is " + i.find('span').text)
```

**Output**:

```
Payment: 賃料 is 7.3万円
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing but I guess the anti-crawler really strong that even your code returns the same meta data

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is because the site is blocking your requests due to the fact that identifies it as coming from a bot.

The usual trick to do that is to attach the same headers (including the cookies) your browser sends in the request. You can see all headers Chrome is sending if you go to `Inspect > Network > Request > Copy > Copy as Curl`.

When you run your script, you get the following:

```
You reached this page when attempting to access https://www.athome.co.jp/chintai/1001303243/?DOWN=2&BKLISTID=002LPC&sref=list_simple&bi=tatemono from 152.172.223.133 on 2019-09-18 02:21:34 UTC.
```

Comment: What did you try exactly. You need to include the whole set of headers and cookies. Do what I suggested by getting the exact curl command from the Chrome console.